# Two-level system Hamiltonian from electric-dipole approx

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, quantum-optics, two-level-system

After making the electric-dipole approx., I can express the interaction of a monochromatic field with angular frequency $\omega$ and a dipole moment ${\bf \mu(x)}$ as

$V({\bf x},t) = - {\bf \mu(x)} \cdot E_0\, sin(\omega t + \phi)$.

I read that in many circumstances, truncation to only a finite number of quantum states is adequate. Apparently the two state approximation results in this expression:

$H_{TLS}(t) = -\frac{1}{2} (E_2 - E_1) \sigma_z - \mu E_0\, sin(\omega t + \phi)\, \sigma_x$.

How does one arrive at this two-level approximation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially asking for the **secular approximation**. The time evolution of the system is governed by the hamiltonian
$$ \hat{H} = \hat{H}_0 + V(x,t),$$
where
$$V(x,t) = -exE_0\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{i\omega t}-e^{-i\omega t}\right).$$
Suppose we know the solutions of the time-dependent Schrödinger equation governed by $\hat{H}_0$ (unperturbed problem) to be
$$ \psi_n(t) = \left|\left. n\right>\right. e^{-i\omega_n t},$$
where the states $\left|\left. n\right>\right.$ are eigenstates of $\hat{H}_0$, and $\hbar\omega_n$ are the corresponding eigenvalues. Then we can expand the solutions of the time-dependent problem in terms of the eigenstates of the unperturbed problem according to
$$ \psi(t) = \sum_n a_n(t)\left|\left. n\right>\right. e^{-i\omega_nt}.$$
Inserting this Ansatz into the time-dependent Schrödinger equation governed by $\hat{H}$ gives a system of equations for the coefficients $a_n(t)$, namely,
$$ i\hbar\partial_t a_m(t) = -\frac{eE}{2i}\sum_n a_n(t)x_{mn}\left(e^{i(\omega_{mn}+\omega)t}-e^{i(\omega_{mn}-\omega)t}\right)$$
with $\omega_{mn}=\omega_m-\omega_n$.

Now we assume that the excitation frequency $\omega$ is very close to the transition frequency $\omega_{fi}$ between an initial state $i$ and a final state $f$, i.e.,
$$ \omega = \omega_{fi}+\epsilon.$$
We further assume that at $t<0$ the system is in the initial state $\left|\left. i\right>\right.$, and that the excitation $V(x,t)$ is switched on abruptly at $t=0$.

The *secular approximation* takes in such a case only the coefficients $a_i(t)$ and $a_f(t)$ into account. This approximation leads to the two coupled equations
$$ i\hbar\partial_t a_i(t) = -\frac{eE}{2i}a_f(t)x_{if}e^{+i\epsilon t}$$
$$ i\hbar\partial_t a_f(t) = +\frac{eE}{2i}a_i(t)x_{if}^\star e^{-i\epsilon t}.$$
This system of equations can be solved exactly. To this end, we define new coefficients $b_i(t)$ and $b_f(t)$ according to
$$ a_i(t) = e^{+i\epsilon t/2}b_i(t)$$
$$ a_f(t) = e^{-i\epsilon t/2}b_f(t)$$
and insert them into the pair of equations above. This leads to
$$ i\hbar\partial_t b_i(t) = \frac{\hbar\epsilon}{2}b_i(t) - \frac{eE}{2i}x_{if}b_f(t)$$
$$ i\hbar\partial_t b_f(t) = \frac{eE}{2i}x_{if}^\star b_i(t) - \frac{\hbar\epsilon}{2}b_f(t). $$
This pair of equations reduces to the harmonic oscillator equations
$$ \partial_t^2 b_{i/f}(t) + \Omega^2b_{i/f}(t) = 0,$$
where
$$ \Omega = \sqrt{\left(\frac{eE}{2\hbar}\right)^2|x_{if}|^2+\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)^2},$$
which is called the *Rabi frequency*.

A more elaborate discussion of the secular approximation is found, e.g, in Cohen-Tannoudji, Quantum Mechanics, Vol. II, chapter XIII (see in particular the complement C$_{\mathrm{XIII}}$).